Как получить chat id из forwarded сообщения (telebot)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['GIF', 'text'])
def check(message):
    for i in adminID:
        if i != message.chat.id:
            bot.forward_message(from_chat_id=message.chat.id, chat_id=i, message_id=message.message_id)
        else:
            if message.reply_to_message:
                user_ID = message.forward_from.id
                bot.send_message(chat_id=user_ID, text=message)

Мой код такой :
я пробовал делать message.forward_from.id но .id нету

Думаю, вам поможет официальная документация telegram. Возможно такие вещи, как forward_origin и MessageOrigin.
